# Tool for managing file routing on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, filesystems, file-management

I would like to be able to see when a file is created/read/edited, and be able to reroute thoughs events to a new location the next time that transaction is executed to another local file path.

**PROBLEM:** An application that does not allow you to manage where it "[creates/reads/updates/deletes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)" files on disk.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no *file routing* in Windows XP.

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg: I'm not 100% sure, do you know anything about monitoring file triggers on Windows?

Comment: The monitoring part can easily be achieved with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It's the second part of your question that concerns me.

Comment: +1 @Oliver Salzburg: Fair enough, beyond the monitor aspect, I really have no idea if it's possible, though wanted to confirm you discounting the feasibility of finding a solution without additional details. To your knowledge, is there any OS that enables this functionality? (The usecase being an application that does not allow you to manage where it writes files to disk.)

Comment: Once you know more about the problem, you could approach this with [NTFS symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) or [Volume Mount Points](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938934.aspx) under Windows.

Comment: +1 @Oliver Salzburg : Awesome, thank you - that info is useful enough to be an answer. NTFS symbolic links appear to be supported in Vista, but for Windows XP, appears [NTFS Junction Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) might work, though I'll have to give it a try, since at this point it's not 100% clear what they will and will not do. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness sake, I repeat the information from my comments in an answer.

#### Monitoring

To see what files an application tries to access, you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).
It will display any file and/or registry access of a process. You can use this information to determine what files are being used by a certain application.

#### Manipulation

To *re-route* what files are being access by a process, you have the following options on Windows:

- [NTFS symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)
- [NTFS junction points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).
- [Volume mount points](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938934.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> is there any OS that enables this functionality?

On Unix/Linux you could create a named pipe that has the name which the application writes to.

You can create a program/script that reads from the named pipe and which writes to a regular file with a name of it's own choosing  and which closes and reopens a new output file with a new name when it sense that is necessary (long pause in input?).

I don't know if NTFS has an equivalent, it well may.